# Mocking an NHibernate ISession with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nhibernate, moq

I am starting a new project with NHibernate, ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and StructureMap and using NUnit and Moq for testing. For each of my controllers I have a single public constructor into which an ISession is being injected. The application itself works just fine, but in terms of unit testing I essentially have to mock an ISession in order to test the controllers.

When I attempt to Mock the ISession with MOQ i get the following error message:

> Only property accesses are supported
>   in intermediate invocations

It appears that my problem is expecting List of users from the framework CreateQuery method but after googling the issue I am now clearer.

I have two questions:

1) Is this the WRONG way to mock dependency injection of an ISession

2) Is there a way to modify the code so that it can successfully return my list

```
            [Test]
            public void DummyTest()
            {

                var mock = new Mock<ISession>();
                var loc = new Mock<User>();
                loc.SetupGet(x => x.ID).Returns(2);
                loc.SetupGet(x => x.FirstName).Returns("John");
                loc.SetupGet(x => x.LastName).Returns("Peterson");

                var lst = new List<User> {loc.Object};
                mock.Setup(framework => framework.CreateQuery("from User").List<User>()).Returns(lst);

                var controller = new UsersController(mock.Object);
                var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
               Assert.IsNotNull(result.ViewData);
            }
```

Please note, I am pretty sure I could just create a hard-coded list of users (rather than mocking an individual User and adding it to a list) but figured I'd leave the code as I have it right now.

Also, the Index action of this particular controller essentially executes the CreateQuery call mimicked above to return all users in the database. This is a contrived example - don't read anything into the details.

Thanks in advance for your help

**Edit: In reply to the below comment, I am adding the stacktrace for the error. Also, all properties on the User class are virtual.**

> TestCase
>   'Beta.Tests.Unit.Controllers.UserControllerTest.Details_InValidIndex_ReturnsNotFoundView'
>   failed: System.NotSupportedException :
>   Only property accesses are supported
>   in intermediate invocations on a
>   setup. Unsupported expression
>   framework.CreateQuery("from User").
>     at
>   Moq.Mock.AutoMockPropertiesVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   m)    at
>   Moq.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)  at
>   Moq.Mock.AutoMockPropertiesVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   m)    at
>   Moq.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)  at
>   Moq.Mock.AutoMockPropertiesVisitor.SetupMocks(Expression
>   expression)   at
>   Moq.Mock.GetInterceptor(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, Mock mock)    at
>   Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass12`2.<Setup>b__11()
>     at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1
>   function)     at
>   Moq.Mock.Setup[T1,TResult](Mock mock,
>   Expression`1 expression)  at
>   Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1
>   expression)
>     Controllers\UserControllerTest.cs(29,0):
>   at
>   Beta.Tests.Unit.Controllers.UserControllerTest.Details_InValidIndex_ReturnsNotFoundView()

Comment: Could you show a stacktrace of the error? Are the User properties abstract or virtual?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Below is the solution I came up with which seems to work perfectly. Again, I am not testing NHibernate and I am not testing the database - I simply want to test the controllers which depend on NHibernate. The issue with the initial solution appears to be the fact that I was calling a Method as well as reading the List member of the session in the MOQ setup call. I broke up these calls by breaking the solution into a QueryMock and a Session Mock (create query returns an IQuery object). A transaction mock was also necessary as it is a dependency (in my case) of the session...

```
        [Test]
        public void DummyTest()
        {
            var userList = new List<User>() { new User() { ID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Peterson" } };
            var sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
            var queryMock = new Mock<IQuery>();
            var transactionMock = new Mock<ITransaction>();

            sessionMock.SetupGet(x => x.Transaction).Returns(transactionMock.Object);
            sessionMock.Setup(session => session.CreateQuery("from User")).Returns(queryMock.Object);
            queryMock.Setup(x => x.List<User>()).Returns(userList);

            var controller = new UsersController(sessionMock.Object);
            var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.ViewData);
        }
```

Answer (score 19):

Rather than mocking the `Session`, one might consider setting up a different `Configuration` for unit-tests. This unit-testing `Configuration` uses a fast, in-process database like SQLite or Firebird. In the fixture setup, you create a new test database completely from scratch, run the scripts to set up the tables, and create a set of initial records. In the per-test setup, you open a transaction and in the post-test teardown, you rollback the transaction to restore the database to its previous state. In a sense, you are not mocking the `Session`, because that gets tricky, but you are mocking the actual database.

Comment: Thanks Justice. I had definitely thought of that and, if i cant get this working, it will be the way I go. But I'm trying to avoid the database altogether in this test project. If I can mock out NHibernate I feel I will have far more control over my tests...but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunately, the NHibernate `Session` is very complicated when it comes to related objects, deferred loading, caching, and all the other things that NHibernate does. So I would just skip trying to mock it and instead try to mock the database. It's easy for NHibernate to generate a schema-creation script for any given database system from your mappings and then for you to execute that script to create an empty database with your schema on fixture-setup. From my own experience with NHibernate and from observing what frameworks like Rails do, this is essentially the only way to go.

Comment: hmm, you are right...altough it would be so nice it we don't need to use some mocked db...if we already have nhibernate which translate our relational model to object model, it is kind of strange to tested like that, we should be able to test it directly...

nice question and answers, cheers :)

Comment: This has been my preferred method. Using things like `SchemaExport` in your `[SetUp]` method just makes things like this all too easy.

Comment: Except that when you do this, you're not running unit testing, you're running an integration test with a database. You've then lost any sort of benefit to writing unit tests.